# Notepad++ opening sql files with characters not text

Tags: sql, notepad++

Initially when using Notepad++ it was opening my sql files no problem as text so that I could edit them, now it's opening them and showing characters instead of text for example;

"‚©§*ÐÊçrQ™êÃÔ ¬™;öý6½ßhÌ³f
Ù¢sùª2’>}^‘NT+^Ú—»hSïèÀWÓá«¹7ãZî·}­G¯ušG¯*cÏŸWt'Vô,"

This is completely meaningless to me and I do not know how to fix this problem. Please help this is so frustrating.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++'s menu, select "Encoding", and then make sure that "Encode in ANSI" is selected.

If this doesn't help, try opening the file in just Notepad.exe, and see if it is still scrambled; if it is, could it be that your files have been corrupted somehow?